# How to get the fullname of the file stored in the temp folder in asp.net mvc 5 app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, httppostedfilebase

I have an app written using c# on the top on ASP.NET MVC 5 framework. One of my pages allow a user to upload file to the server. So I use `HttpPostedFileBase` to upload the file to the server.

However, instead on saving the file to a permanent place, I am hoping be able to extract the fullname of the file and work on it before moving it to a permanent place.

How can I get the temp full-name of the uploaded file?

I tried the following, but the check `File.Exists(tempFullname)` always fails.

```
public string GetFullname(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string tempFullname = Path.GetTempPath() + file.FileName;

    if(File.Exists(tempFullname))
    {
        return tempFullname;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

I also tried the following but `temp.Length` throw an exception as the file does not exists

```
public string GetFullname(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    string temp = new FileInfo(file.FileName);

    if(temp.Length > 0)
    {
        return tempFullname;
    }

    return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: Why *would* it exist?

Comment: @SamAxe maybe I am missing the idea of the upload process. but in my mind, when the file in uploaded, it is automatically put into the temp folder then one my chose to move it to a permanent place using the `SaveAs()` method.

Comment: Unless you write code to place the file on disk, then the file doesn't exist on the disk.  The file only exists as a byte stream in memory (attached to the HttpPostedFileBase instance; InputStream property) until you copy it somewhere.

Comment: the file data is in memory inside your `file` variable, nowhere else. The temp folder is not involved at all.

Answer (score -1):

To get the full name of need to save the file first, i can't get the location of a file if you don't save it first!

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("<A folder you want>"), file.FileName);

file.Save(filePath);
```

In this way, filePath is the full path of your file